# Drop-down boxes not working on PC Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://getinjuryanswers.com/practice-areas/car-accidents/

I have noticed that on PC the drop down boxes containing additional content sometimes do not work (nothing happens when you click the link). I'm not sure if there is something that I need to insert into the code to get it to work properly on PC (I use MAC, so I didn't notice this at first).

The odd part is that the error seems to fix itself after about a minute of the page loading, which makes me wonder if there some related javascript issue (the box doesn't expand until javascript loads, but I don't there is any javascript component to this drop-down functionality.)

Here is the code. If anyone has seen something like this, any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks.

CSS:

```
.panel-group .panel {
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.panel-default {
    border-color: #dddddd;
}
.panel {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.panel-default > .panel-heading {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-color: #dddddd;
    color: #333333;
}
.panel-group .panel-heading {
    border-bottom: 0 none;
}
.panel-heading {
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
.panel-title {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
.panel-title {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div id="headingOne" class="panel-heading">
<p class="panel-title">
<a class="collapsed" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse9">Get the Compensation You Deserve</a>
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't see any dropdown boxes in your code

Comment: Are you referring to the hover effect on the top menu? There are no `select` elements on the page.

Comment: Hi, sorry for not being clear. If you go to the page, scroll down to the header - "Why Retain An Experienced Legal Team" - below that you'll see two grey boxes with links. When you click on either one, it should expand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't saw any issues while testing in my Chrome.

That collapsible element works because of the Bootstrap's Javascript component named `Collapse`. Read more about it [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse). So it definitely has some javascript behind the scenes that does the work.

The possible reasons for it to break are:

- The page was not completely loaded when you were trying to click on those collapse buttons. So no click events were binded with those buttons as the javascript code might not even had executed yet. So that could be one reason and that's what I think is the real reason. Try waiting for the page to completely load and see if it doesn't causes any issues after that.
- Another possibility is that, suppose if there's a Javascript error in the page, the javascript code beneath it might not be executed. So check your Javascript Console for any possible errors. You could access your Developer Tools(it contains various useful stuff for debugging) in Google Chrome by pressing Ctrl+Shift+I. If there's any javascript errors, try to fix it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. I figured it might be the that the javascript hadn't loaded. I'm wondering if I could make that particular javascript code load faster.